# Ayuda con el SDK visual Studio

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Necesito que el *SDK* del *Visual* para *Android* tenga instaladas las versiones de *Android* para las cuales quiero desarrollar.

Es decir, si quiero desarrollar para *Android 4.4* ¿Debo tener instalada esta *API*?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si específicamente quieres desarrollar para la versión Android 4.4 definiendo un [targetSdkVersion](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Android.Content.PM.ApplicationInfo.TargetSdkVersion/) :

```
targetSdkVersion 19
```

es obvio instalar.

Pero pongo otro caso, suponiendo quieres desarrollar para Android 5.0 (Lollipop), esto definiendo un

```
 targetSdkVersion 21
```

y el dispositivo que usaras para la aplicación tiene sistema operativo Android 4.4, con esto no es necesario tener instalada la API 19 (KitKat).

---

Existen otras propiedades importantes [MinSdkVersion](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/field/Android.Resource+Attribute.MinSdkVersion/) y [MaxSdkVersion](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/field/Android.Resource+Attribute.MaxSdkVersion/) que definen entre que sistemas operativos tu aplicación sería soportada.

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

La respuesta es, *sí*. Debes tener instalda esa **API**.